# JavaScript: what does Object(variable)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I ran into a boolean test `variable === Object(variable)` but couldn't find anything that describes it.

Is it testing that `variable` is the same as `Object(variable)` and does `Object(variable)` cast this `variable` into object? Or does it do something else?

If it matches it will loop `for (var key in variable)` and uses `key` and `variable[key]` as parameters for another function. If it fails it uses just that variable as is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It checks that

1. the variable is defined
2. its value is an object
3. its value isn't `null` (be careful: `typeof null` is `"object"`)

This is probably the simplest way to check these 3 conditions and it looks like a reasonable test to run before to loop on keys in a very polymorphic function.

Another one would have been `typeof variable === "object" && variable`.

From [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object):

> The Object constructor creates an object wrapper for the given value.
>   If the value is null or undefined, it will create and return an empty
>   object, otherwise, it will return an object of a Type that corresponds
>   to the given value. If the value is an object already, it will return
>   the value.

Comment: Perfect! "If the value is an object already, it will return the value." I was on the wrong page in MDN: Object.protoype. So, close but not close enough :)